# query parameter validation with Jersey

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs, bean-validation

I'm using Jersey in Java for a simple web server. I'm trying to handle with url query parameters, like

```
/path?value1=X&value2=Y&value3=Z
```

I was able to extract the query value by using the @QueryParam annotation like

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Path("/path")
public String getUpdate(@QueryParam("All") List<String> allParam, 
        @QueryParam(value = "value1") String value1, 
        @QueryParam(value = "value2") String value2, 
        @QueryParam(value = "value3") String value3) {
        ...
}
```

Now my problem is I need to validate the input. I'm mainly trying to make sure that value1, value2 and value3 follow a specific format. I also want to make sure that those parameters are not empty.

I checked out the Bean Validation documentation for Jersey, but it seemed hard to follow. This is probably because I'm still somewhat new to Jersey framework.

So how can I set up query parameter validations? Are there easier to follow resources/examples I could be directed to? Thanks

Answer (score 13):

As @VA31 linked, you can use bean validation like this, if your jersey is latest enough.

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Path("/path")
public Response getUpdate(
    @QueryParam("value1")
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 255)
    @Pattern(regexp = "\\d+")
    String value1, 
    @QueryParam("value2")
    @Min(52)
    @Max(53)
    int value2, 
    @QueryParam("value3")
    @NotNull
    Integer value3) {


}
```

Comment: Will jersey give a bad request, if the required validation turns out to be false ?

Comment: @PratikSinghal Yes it does! `400` will be responded with counterintuitive message.